# How to loop through this JSON Data using Jquery to display klout score?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

API JSON Data:

```
{"status":200,"users":[{"twitter_screen_name":"mikerbrt","influencers":
[{"twitter_screen_name":"techcrunch","kscore":85.17},    
{"twitter_screen_name":"tinucherian","kscore":61.5},
{"twitter_screen_name":"scobleizer","kscore":84.08},
{"twitter_screen_name":"startwerk","kscore":42.12},
{"twitter_screen_name":"mikeschwede","kscore":61.89}]}]}
```

Script:

```
$( "#getTweets" ).bind( "click", function() {
    var twitterUsername = $( "#twitterUsername" ).val();   
     var url = "http://api.klout.com/1/soi/influenced_by.json?key=7zcwhzhdp4w45q9fdqw9gqsc" + "&users=" +  twitterUsername + "&callback=?";
    $.getJSON( url, function( data ) {
             for(var i=0; i < data.influencers.length; i++) {
  alert(data.influencers[i].kscore);
      } 
           });
});
```

HTML Data:

```
<div id="input">
    <span>Enter Twitter Username</span>
    <input id="twitterUsername" type="text" />
    <button id="getTweets">Get Tweets</button>
</div>
<ul></ul>
```

Required Output: Need to display klout score of influencers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, I'm not sure if "Users" property will be treated as an array, or a Single Instance or users, but it will be either :

```
for(var i=0; i < data.users[0].influencers.length; i++) {
  alert(data.users[0].influencers[i].kscore);
}
```

or

```
for(var i=0; i < data.users.influencers.length; i++) {
  alert(data.users.influencers[i].kscore);
}
```

depending on how "users" is perceieved
HTH.
Dave

Comment: Hi Dave, Following solution is working:for(var i=0; i < data.users[0].influencers.length; i++) {
  alert(data.users[0].influencers[i].kscore);
}   Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

You aren't selecting the `users` in `data.users.influencers`:

```
$.getJSON( url, function( data ) {
  $.each(data.users,function(u,users){
     $.each(users.influencers,function(i,user){
      alert(user.kscore);
     });
  });     
}
```

Comment: @Dave Long your solution made me realize users was an array instead of an object though :)

Comment: I was also confused by that - and proceeded to edit my answer :-)

Comment: @Niklas, would that not be 
$.each(data.users,function(u,user){
     $.each(user.influensers,function(i,influenser){
      alert(influenser.kscore);
     });
  });

Comment: @Niklalalas - I added a version too

Answer (score 0):

since you only get ONE user's data, you can do this:

### [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/AfsCc/)

```
<div id="input">
    <span>Enter Twitter Username</span>
    <input id="twitterUsername" type="text" />
    <button id="getTweets">Get Tweets</button>
</div>
<ul id="klout"></ul>

$( "#getTweets" ).bind( "click", function() {
    var twitterUsername = $( "#twitterUsername" ).val();   
     var url = "http://api.klout.com/1/soi/influenced_by.json?key=7zcwhzhdp4w45q9fdqw9gqsc" + "&users=" +  twitterUsername + "&callback=?";
    $.getJSON( url, function( data ) {
        $.each(data.users[0].influencers,function(j, influenser) { // array
  $("#klout").append('<li>'+influenser.twitter_screen_name+':'+influenser.kscore+'</li>');
       });
    });
});
```